# AMQP with transaction manager in RPC model

Tags: spring-transactions, spring-amqp

I am using spring-amqp/RabbitMQ for my project with RPC. I am able to send and receive message via message broker without any problem.

Here is my working code

```
<bean id="stbListener"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.remoting.service.A mqpInvokerServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.java.stb.service.api.STBService" />
    <property name="service" ref="stbService" />
    <property name="amqpTemplate" ref="template" />
</bean>

<bean id="stbService" class="com.java.stb.service.impl.STBServiceImpl" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
    channel-cache-size="10" />
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    auto-startup="false" />
<rabbit:template id="template" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    channel-transacted="true" />

<rabbit:queue name="${queue}" />

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener ref="stbListener" queue-names="${queue}" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

And recently i added @transactional annotation in some my producer method for  get/insert/update data in Postgres. Now i am having issue to get message from producer. I copied my producer code below with added transaction manager

```
<bean id="stbListener"
class="org.springframework.amqp.remoting.service.A mqpInvokerServiceExporter">
<property name="serviceInterface" value="com.java.stb.service.api.STBService" />
<property name="service" ref="stbService" />
<property name="amqpTemplate" ref="template" />
</bean>


<bean id="rabbitTxManager"
class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.transaction .RabbitTransactionManager">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="stbService" class="com.java.stb.service.impl.STBServiceImpl" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
channel-cache-size="10" />
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"
auto-startup="false" />
<rabbit:template id="template" connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
channel-transacted="true" />

<rabbit:queue name="${queue}" />

<rabbit:listener-container concurrency="20" prefetch="20" transaction-size="10" auto-startup="false" 
connection-factory="connectionFactory" transaction-manager="rabbitTxManager">
<rabbit:listener ref="stbListener" queue-names="${queue}" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

i am getting timeout error which is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.remoting.RemoteProxyFailureExc eption: No reply received - perhaps a timeout in the template?
at org.springframework.amqp.remoting.client.AmqpClien tInterceptor.invoke(AmqpClientInterceptor.java:60)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethod Invocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java :172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopPro xy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.isIdentityAvailableForSTB(Un known Source)
at tv.moonweb.stb.service.api.STBServiceClient.isIden tityAvailableForSTB(STBServiceClient.java:101)
... 17 more
```

I set `reply-timeout="10000"` in consumer side.

Please help me to solve this problem

Thank-you in advance

Gopy

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you turn on debug logging on both sides; if you can't figure out what the problem is, post the logs somewhere and we can take a look.

It's not clear why you added a Rabbit Transaction manager on the consumer side when you said you added `@Transactional` on the producer side.

If your STBServiceImpl talks to a DB, the transaction manager should be a JDBC transaction manager.

If you want a downstream `RabbitTemplate` to participate in the inbound session, the message listener container needs `channel-transacted` too - otherwise the listener runs in a non-transactional Channel.

Comment: i added '@transactional' in producer side only. Now i tried with 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager and 'channel-transacted="true"' in listner container. still same issue, i will enable debug and update to you. One more thing i am facing this issue only in virgo server not in eclipse

Comment: I found myself. This is my current listner configuration, <rabbit:listener-container channel-transacted="true" connection-factory="connectionFactory">
  <rabbit:listener   ref="stbListener" queue-names="${stb.queue}" />
 </rabbit:listener-container>
thank you